# Find an replace regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex that finds

```
width="any number px"
```

I tried `[width=\".*px\"]`

To be clear I have file like

```
1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" viewBox="0 0
```

and I need to get

```
1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used a literal in a character class.

Try replacing matches of this:

```
width="\d+px"\s*
```

with a blank (to delete it)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to match 'any number'

the `\d` sequence will match any single digit.
`[0-9]` will do the same.

Following either of these with `+` will match any instance of one or more of these.

So `width=\"[0-9]+px\"` will find the matches you want.

Also, containing the entire query in `[` `]` turns it into a character class, meaning that instead of finding the exact string, it will return any instance of any of the characters in the class. `[width]` will find any single instance of the letters `w`, `i`, `d`, `t` or `h`, regardless of where they are.